# Data coalescence between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have been attempting to crack this nut for several hours now but I cannot figure out what combination of query code is required to achieve the exact results I am looking for.

I have two tables:

Music and Playlists

The fields for Music:

ID (Primary), Track_Name, File_Path, Date_Added, Artist, Album

The fields for Playlists:

PID, ID (many-to-one relation with Music), Number_of_Plays

What I am trying to do is for each ID in Music combine all of the records in all Playlists and then sum the Number_of_Plays field

Here is as far as I have gotten:

```
Select Music.ID, Music.Track_Name, Playlists.PID From Music
Join Playlists On Music.ID = Playlists.ID
Where Playlists.ID In (
Select ID From Playlists
Group By ID
Having Count(Number_of_Plays) > 1)
```

The only thing this produces is a list ordered by ID of records that have more than one number of plays. I have been able to figure out part of the second half of the problem where the number of plays for a song across all playlists is summed together but not how to not display those records where Number_of_Plays equals 1.  Here is the query that I found did part of the second half of what is required:

```
select PID, ID, sum(Number_of_Plays) As Total from Playlists
group by PID, ID LEFT(`ID`,11)
order by PID
```

This combines the Number_of_Plays field based on the value of ID but does not remove records that only have 1 play on them.  I have been trying for the last 45 minutes to combine these two queries somehow but I have gotten nothing but syntax error messages spit back at me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out:

```
Select Music.ID, Music.track_name, Playlists.PI, sum(Playlists.Number_of_Plays) As Total_Plays From Music
Join Playlists On Music.ID = Playlists.ID
Group By Playlist.ID, LEFT('ID', 11) Having Count(Playlist.ID) > 1
```

This produced a resultset that had the records ordered by ID and had the number of plays summed.